# dynamic "lambda_function" with for_each in Terraform leads to blocks swapping places on every plan/apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform file that contains an `aws_s3_bucket_notification` resource with a `dynamic "lambda_function"` block containing the filters and notifications for all the lambdas that are to be notified. These lambdas are built from a config file, hence I need the `lambda_function` block in the notification config to be `dynamic`.

For some reason though it happens that the resulting `lambda_function` blocks that are created dynamically, swap places. They get renamed in cycles, destroyed and rebuilt in a way that after the deployment everything's the same as before, only in a different order.

How can I make sure that this swapping and switching and shuffling does not happen? Is there a way to give the resulting dynamic blocks an ID that is somehow related to the iterator of the for_each? Or are there other means for achieving peace there?

Here's some generalized terraform code that reflects what I have (not the original code, as mentioned in my comment below):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "notification_config" {
  bucket = local.bucket

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = local.configs
    content {
      lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:${local.region}:${local.account_id}:function:${lambda_function.key}"
      filter_prefix = lambda_function.value.filter_prefix
      events = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the terraform code

Comment: I kind of have in my answer below. I can copy it to my question if need be. My original terraform code is confidential, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than expected: by using the field `id` in the `dynamic "lambda_function"` block:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "notification_config" {
  bucket = local.bucket

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = local.configs
    content {
      lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:${local.region}:${local.account_id}:function:${lambda_function.key}"
      filter_prefix = lambda_function.value.filter_prefix
      events = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      id     = "${lambda_function.key}-notification"
    }
  }
}
```